# Getting error "PHP extension "curl" must be loaded" in installation of Magento

Tags: php, magento, curl, dll, wamp

I don't know why Magento is showing this warning on installation. I have windows 7, wamp-server2.2(Apache Version :2.4.4,PHP Version :5.4.16)

I have done following things 
1- remove ; from ;extension=php_curl.dll in all the wamp files php.ini. 
2- placed ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll. and php_curl.dll file into windows/system32 folder and restart pc. 
3. Also update the php_curl.php file from http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ .

if i run

```
  <?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

it does't show the extension but if i run

```
curl --help
```

from the command prompt, it shows all the help command

I am not able to resolve out this...

Comment: May be php_curl.dll is corrupted. Try to download new one and replace with old one and restart wamp server.

Comment: @RajivRanjan i have downloaded 3-4 times....

Comment: php_curl.dll should be on this directory: wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext not in windows/system32.

Comment: php_curl.dll is present in the wamp\bin\php\php*\ext folder but it is not picking either.....

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with the curl extension from wamp2.2 on win7.
You can download the "fixed" curl dll from here: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
Look at the section "Fixed curl extensions:" and get one for php 5.4. Replace the curl dll with that one and restart your server.

Comment: @aligarian. To be honest I never tried it for php 5.4. I had the same issue with php 5.3 and this solved my problem.